# GLM view matrix causing model matrix to have no effect

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math

I'm trying to get an object to always face the camera. I looked up a way to do this, but the problem is when I put this part into the view matrix nothing is affected by the model matrix. How can I get it to translate it using the model matrix? code:

```
GLuint transformLocation=glGetUniformLocation(textureShaders,"transform");
glm::mat4 transform;
glm::mat4 model;
glm::vec3 playerPosition=user.getPosition();

model=glm::translate(model,glm::vec3(xpos,0.0f,zpos));

glm::mat4 view;
     view=glm::lookAt(cam.getPositionVector(),cam.getPositionVector()+cam.getFrontVector(),cam.getUpVector());
glm::mat4 rotationMatrix=glm::transpose(glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(xpos,0.0f,zpos),playerPosition,glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f)));
view*=rotationMatrix;
glm::mat4 projection;
projection=glm::perspective(45.0f,(float)900/(float)600,0.1f,100.0f);

transform=projection*view*model;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is affected by the model matrix"?

Comment: The translation I put there does not seem to work. (It stays at (0,0,0))

Comment: Well, have you checked what your transform matrix looks like now?

Comment: The code looks all right to me. The problem might originate outside it. Are you setting the 'transform' matrix into the shader uniform (or just projection*view)?

Comment: I am setting the uniform into the shader correctly because the rotation works, it's just the translation I'm having problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "rotation" matrix doesn't really make sense:

```
rotationMatrix=glm::transpose(glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(xpos,0.0f,zpos),playerPosition,glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f)));
```

This will *not* result in a rotation matrix (except when both `xpos` and `zpos` happen to be zero). `lookAt` will create a transform matrix which can be decomposed to `r * t(-pos)` (for whatever `pos` you call it with). Building the *transpose* of this matrix will result in the translation column beeing transposed to the fourth row, which completely will screw the final `w` coordinate.

Comment: So how would I set up a rotation matrix?

Comment: The easiest way seems to be to directly builld an ortogonal matrix from yout camera right, up and forward vectors. When you want an flact object to always face the camera, this just means that you want to rotate the plane it is lying in to a plane parallel to the image plane. Your camera 's right and up vectors define that plane.